# CatBoostError: catboost/libs/train_lib/dir_helper.cpp:20: Can't create train working dir:

Tags: machine-learning, databricks, catboost

I am running catboost on Databricks cluster. Databricks Production cluster is very secure and we cannot create new directory on the go as a user. But we can have pre-created directories. I am passing below parameter for my CatBoostClassifier.
`CatBoostClassifier(train_dir='dbfs/FileStore/files/')`
It does not work and throws below error.
`CatBoostError: catboost/libs/train_lib/dir_helper.cpp:20: Can't create train working dir`

Answer (score 0):

you're missing `/` character at the beginning - it should be `'/dbfs/FileStore/files/'` instead.

Also, writing to DBFS could be slow, and may fail if catboost is using random writes (see [limitations](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-api-limitations)).  You may instead point to the local directory of the node, like, `/tmp/....`, and then use `dbutils.fs.cp("file:///tmp/....", "/FileStore/files/catboost/...", True)` to copy files from local directory to the DBFS.